# How do you locate the source code for a CALL in php?

Tags: php

I wrote some fairly complicated calculation logic. At one point during the calculations I call a mini calculation that gets run as part of the main calculation. I wrote that calculation separately and I am able to call that mini calculation using "CALL" then the name I gave it ("hours-calculation"). So "CALL hours-calculation" is a working mini calculation within my main set of calculations, but I have misplaced where I wrote that logic for the mini calculation. I can call it but I can't find it to alter it - even when I search the files for "CALL hours-calculation" I can only find the references to calling it and not the code itself. Any ideas how to find it?

Comment: Maybe [`debug_print_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php)?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the root of your project and execute `grep -ri 'hours-calculation'`, it will search all files for the pattern.